# FreeBSD - delete a partially installed gnome2?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, bsd-ports, uninstall, gnome2

I've been trying to compile x11/gnome2 under FreeBSD 10.0-REL, but have been running into all sorts of issues.  Eventually I found things indicating that gnome2 is no longer really supported, and that I should use something else (MATE, Xfce, KDE, whatever) instead.

But gnome2 installs a trillion other packages, none of which I actually want if I'm not going to be using Gnome.  So "make install" of gnome2 has failed, but not before installing a few billion packages that I don't want.  I'd like to get rid of them before starting an install of Xfce or whatever.

How can I easily delete those that aren't needed by anything that doesn't ultimately go back go the gnome2 package? So, in a perfect world I'd like a command that says:

"Figure out all packages that are supposed to be installed via gnome2 (including recursively).  For each such package, if it is installed, uninstall it *unless* there is some installed package that needs it and that is *not* among those installed via gnome2 (including recursively)."

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, I currently have very few packages that I explicitly want installed (though many that I need because of those very few).  Is there a way to say, for example, "deinstall anything that is not needed by apache24, subversion, or viewvc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD 10 comes with `pkg` utility that allows you to do exactly that:

```
pkg autoremove
```

See `pkg help` for the full list of `pkg` commands.

You probably will need to clean the port after failed build as well.
You can do it this way:

```
cd /usr/ports/x11/gnome2
make clean
```

About your second question: yes, there is a way. You should delete packages that require these dependencies and then execute `pkg autoremove`, it will do the rest.